# Toggle between event handlers in gtk2hs

Tags: haskell, event-handling, gtk, gtk2hs

I would like to do something like this:

```
handlerOn = do
  cid <- canvas `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent do
    signalDisconnect cid
    handlerOff
  putStrLn "handlerOn"

handlerOff = do
  cid <- canvas `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent do
    signalDisconnect cid
    handlerOn
  putStrLn "handlerOff"
```

This won't work as it is, of course, because I'm trying to use cid inside a code block where cid is not assigned yet.

The idea is to register an event listener that when it receives an event, it will deregister itself and register a different event listener which will do the same, back and forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC supports [recursive `do`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#recursive-do-notation).

```
handlerOn = do
  rec cid <- canvas `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent do
    signalDisconnect cid
    handlerOff
  putStrLn "handlerOn"
```

You could also use `Control.Monad.Fix`.

```
handlerOff = do
  mfix $ \cid -> canvas `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent do
    signalDisconnect cid
    handlerOn
  putStrLn "handlerOff"
```

Or manage the handler yourself.

```
do ...
    h <- newIORef undefined
    let handlerOn = do
            ...
            writeIORef h handlerOff
        handlerOff = do
            ...
            writeIORef h handlerOn
    writeIORef h handlerOn
    canvas `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent =<< readIORef h
```

Or just make everything into a single handler.

```
do ...
    ms <- newIORef False
    canvas `on` buttonPressEvent $ tryEvent do
        s <- readIORef ms
        if s
            then ...
            else ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using the first option and at least for me, I had to add braces as in: rec { cid ... handlerOff } for it to work.